# how does sort comparison get it's arguments from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, comparison

I'm reading JavaScript For Web Developer 3rd Edition and I am stuck how this works.  I understand how the compare function works.  But values.sort(compare); confuses me.  compare looks at 2 arguments and compares them.  But I do not pass 2 arguments.  Even if I did pass 2 arguments to the function, how does it compare itself to the rest of the items in the Array?  Does the sort function do something in the background that I don't know about?  If so, how does it work?
Thank you in advance :)

```js
function compare(value1, value2) 
{
 if (value1 < value2) {
 return 1;
 } else if (value1 > value2) {
 return -1;
 } else {
 return 0;
 }
}

var values = [0, 1, 5, 10, 15];
values.sort(compare);
alert(values); //15,10,5,1,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compare function is a call back function that you supply to the sort function. The sort function will use some algorithm to sort the list. When the sort function's algorithm needs to compare two items from the list, the sort method will call the compare function with the two items.

Comment: I see.  Thank you for the reply :) So the sort algorithm will see that I have an array of x items and automatically  grab 2 items in the array and use them for my compare function recursively until it is sorted?

Comment: There is no recursion there. Check some sorting algorithm, eg a bubble sort and implement it yourself. Then you would be able to so what's the purpose of comparison function.